# How to display just a area of the map in color in Mapbox Studio and the rest in black?

Tags: mapbox-studio

I am new in Mapbox programming and I used Mapbox Studio to create my first style.

I would like to configure a polygon that inside the polygon, the map is in color, with all the detail that you can expect of a map, and outside the polygon, the map is BLACK (no street, no building...)

How can i do it with mapbox studio ?

Thanks for your help

I would like to have have a style that represent in color only the aerea in color and the rest in black.

The area can be a town, a park, a forest...